# How do you export your finished application from Xcode?

Tags: xcode, compilation, finalize

I feel silly for having to ask this.  I've got an application to a point where I want to send someone a beta to test on their machine, but I don't know how to get Xcode to produce a `.app` file for me to send to them.  Help?

Comment: Don't feel silly. It's absurd how difficult it is to find information on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Xcode 13 you need to choose `Product -> Destination -> Any iOS device (arm64)`.

Then afterwards you can run `Product -> Archive`.

Comment: Moving the accepted answer to here to reflect the current state of Xcode.  Thanks for the updated info!

Answer (score 68):

This has changed in Xcode 4.

Now Apps can be exported from the "Organizer"

If you haven't already, you need to create an `Archive`.

On the menu go to `Product -> Archive`

Once you're in the `Organizer - Archives` screen click `Share` or `Distribute...` (Xcode 4.3.3 or newer)

Then choose the format you want to export.

Comment: As of XCode 4.3.3, the button is labeled `Distribute...` instead of `Share`

Comment: if Product -> Archive is grayed out (disabled) you have to switch the scheme destination to "iOS Device" (explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18791703/333283)

Comment: This worked for me...I just wanted to know how big my app was. I'm curious: how does Apple control private distribution if they now allow exports?

Answer (score 10):

the app is generally under your

```
project_dir/build/Debug/Name Of App 
project_dir/build/Release/Name Of App
project_dir/build/Distribution/Name Of App
```

depending on which configuration of build you did or want to send.

Answer (score 0):

to get to the .app application you have to go into the folder where you created it into build the your app will be there