# Generate app file for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am not sure how to generate app file for iPhone. I developed app in xcode 4.2. I just want to get the .app file, so I can show to my friends and test on mobile.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess one option would be to generate a provisioning profile, then follow the steps involved in that process to upload it to your friends iPods.

**Or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812650/how-do-you-export-your-finished-application-from-xcode) might help you out.**

Comment: I changed device to the iOS device. Now archive option is enabled but I get this error when I click on it:
The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain

Do I need to have developer account for making test app??

Comment: So, there is no other way to test app on iPhone before buying the Developer licence?

Comment: Nope, not on an iPhone itself. Only the iOS Simulator

Answer (score 0):

Read the "Test Your App on an iOS Device" part: [Manage your workflow in Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/CreateYourAppinXcode/StartYourProjectinXcode/StartYourProjectinXcode.htmlapple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-TP40007593-CH2-DontLinkElementID_1#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-TP40007593-CH2-DontLinkElementID_1)

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://www.eridenttech.com/companion-guideline-submitting-iphone-apps-to-the-apple-app-store.html/%E2%80%9CThis%22) under Archive section it has mentioned very descriptive. If you have any problem ,let me know.