# What is the .ipa file in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, swift

I am currently trying to apply for the WWDC 2015 student scholarship, but Apple requires the .ipa file. The directions state, `"Package your compiled app file in a .zip file. For iOS apps, this refers to the .ipa file."` How do I get this?

Comment: I hope you have read [WWDC Scholarship Guidelines and Terms](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/scholarships/Scholarship-Guidelines-and-Terms.pdf)

Comment: check this link..it explained it beautifully http://stackoverflow.com/a/25971065/1865424

Comment: @RehaanAdvani, do you have the free or paid developer account?

Answer (score 3):

I would break into steps

If you have a clean running app,

- Set your build target as **iOS device** and not simulator
- Product>**archive*
- **Export** it once archiving is done and you get the ipa file
  [image: Export using suitable method]

Answer (score 1):

> `.IPA` is extension of ios app installer package,as windows has
>   `.exe`,android has `.apk`.

`"Package your compiled app file in a .zip file"`

According to this statement,you must be having **iOS or Mac app developed** and they want you to provide your app to them in compressed format(ie.**zip**)