# Testing Push Notifications, sharing app internally with coworkers

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, push-notification, beta-testing

I've made a very basic app for push notifications using my personal ios developer account.  I wanted to share this with a remote coworker but it's proving to be a struggle.

I added his device to my developer account, and I've created a new provisioning profile with his device for my app.

I sent him the certificate, and he ran it on his computer.. and then built the app on his phone.  He got this error:

**Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application" UserInfo=0x17007e880 {NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application}**

i had him check Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts and this is his screen.  I think he has an expired developer account, but can somehow still build apps on his phone??

[image]

he doesnt want to pay the $99.  I'd add him as a developer on my "team" but I have an account as a single developer.  What is the **easiest** way to get this working?

Comment: Why don't you build the app for him, send him the ipa for him to install via iTunes on his device?

Comment: can i have more details please

Comment: In Xcode choose Product->Archive. Then in the organizer tap Export, and then Save for Ad Hoc Deployment. Send him (email, DropBox, etc) the resulting .ipa file. He drops it onto iTunes and syncs his device.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970741/how-to-create-ipa-in-xcode-6) is the link that would help you build ipa that you can share with your coworker.
Or submit your build on iTunes connect and share it via test flight.

And one more thing you should keep in mind that as you mentioned that this app supports push notifications, i hope you have placed development or production SSL certificate on server which is necessary to send notifications from serve to device.