# How Xcode run any app in simulator or Device, and how does the build process work?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

I want to know all work done by Xcode behind the screen to convert code to executable file and also want to know the archive process.

I know the process of command line tools - please give me any reference of any other document if you have.

Comment: You want how to create IPA file. Right?

Comment: Yes, How Xcode create a iPA file

Comment: Please follow this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970741/how-to-create-ipa-in-xcode-6

Comment: These all links showing step by step process to create a .ipa file but i wants to know internal process of Xcode.

Comment: These all link say the steps to create the .ipa while i want to know more then this, How Xcode check dependencies and what is the write auxiliary files all things in details.