# how to generate IPA file as a developer role in Apple developer Account

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

My manager had a Apple developer account, and he added me in his account as a Developer role. Now i have to give him an IPA file. Is it possible for me to generate an IPA file by just signing in with my Apple ID(not a developer account) in Xcode 7..??
I have tried this, but its showing me as FREE role in Preference instead of developer role. Also export button is not enabled after archive is done.

Comment: you signing with your manager developer account and the certificate which you are using after build is matching with your manager developer account.

Comment: check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970741/how-to-create-ipa-in-xcode-6

Comment: Use TestFlight and share the ipa by adding him as a internal tester.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, In xcode 7 above there is no opting for export ipa. But we can do some other ways to generate iPa file.

Follow the below steps:

1. Select product --> Archive option
   [image]
2. And right click on WifiList and select **Show in Finder**
   [image]
3. It will open folder and then right click on folder option "**Show Package Contents**"
   [image]
4. Now you can on file then you can drag and drop on iTunes. 
   [image]
   [image]
5. Drag and drop desktop.

I hope, It will help you.

Comment: And also check that you have installed valid certificate & provisioning profile and selected them in build setting.

Comment: from where to get certificates and where to install it..??
I got IPA file from above procedure but i havn't installed any certificates.plz help me

Comment: You will get certificate from Apple developer account. Please don't ask how to create certificate