# Xcode has conflicting provisioning settings

Tags: ios, xcode, angular, ionic2, xcode8

I have an Ionic 2 app, which builds and is testable in `Xcode 8.2.1` Simulator environment, e.g. `iPhone7` (`Build Successful`).

[image]

When I try `Archive` the app to create an `ipa` file to set on a device, I follow [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970741/how-to-create-ipa-in-xcode-6) instructions. But `Product -> Archive` is greyed out. So I change the active scheme to `Generic iOS Device`.

[image]

But then when I click `Product -> Archive`, I get `Build Failed`.

> theWhoZoo has conflicting provisioning settings. theWhoZoo is
>   automatically signed for development, but a conflicting code signing
>   identity iPhone Distribution has been manually specified. Set the code
>   signing identity value to "iPhone Developer" in the build settings
>   editor, or switch to manual signing in the project editor. Code
>   signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'

[image]

If anyone could advise how I can fix this to build an Archive, I would appreciate it.

Comment: You need apple developer premium account, Once you purchase, add new account in settings of Xcode & sign the IPA with new profiles, see more on apple developer programs https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look. Does that mean on iOS, for development (no paying), toy can't test an app on an actual devise?

Comment: I do have a development (individual) Apple ID already set up, so I don't think that's the reason for the above errors.

Answer (score 140):

**This worked perfectly for me. Give a try :)**

Step 1:

Select the Project Target-- > Build Settings. Search PROVISIONING_PROFILE and delete whatever nonsense is there.

Step 2:

Uncheck "Automatically manage signing", then check it again and reselect the Team. Xcode then fix whatever was causing the issue on its own.

Answer (score 43):

The problem is in Code Signing Identity.  This is a new problem that showed up on the latest release of Xcode. Go to Code Signing Identity, then add other and type in "iPhone Developer" as shown in the error message and save then this will display.[image]

If this does not work show me your General signing. and your Code Signing Identity from both your Project and your Targets

Comment: This answer is old and a better way to fix this in Xcode 8 is to uncheck the Automatically manage signing box in the General tab.  Then recheck the box and reselect the Team.   This fixes this issue without having to edit Code Signing Identity.

Comment: Your welcome, and yes this issue still appears in Xcode 9

Comment: @ThomasDegroot Wooow! Awesome answer! Thanks a lot! Saved my time.

Comment: With Xcode 11 you still have to set this value using the "other" option. It displays "iOS Developer" but in git you can see that it's a different value.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is in Code Signing Identity. This is a new problem that showed up on the latest release of Xcode. Go to Code Signing Identity, make all IOS Developer rather that IOS distribution.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE** Just figured out the real issue [assuming that your app has the correct provisioning profiles, but a target for your app does not]: Navigate to your target and change the provisioning profile there. See below:
[image]
[image]

---

I got this error when I added a target to enable rich push notifications. The project/workspace, "Spontit" did not have this error but the target "RichNotification" did.

I tried several things, and the last thing I did, that seemed to be responsible for it finally working, was:

- Un-add and re-add the embedded binary for the target "RichNotification" in the "General" tab of the project, "Spontit".
  [image]
- Another thing to check is to make sure that it is added as a "Target Dependency" in the "Build Phases" tab.
  [image]
- For this particular problem, make sure to clean your project (Cmd Shift K) before building it, every time. Otherwise, you might fix it and try to build it and think it's not working, but really it's using the old settings- so clean it first.

Answer (score 2):

For me Only this worked.I tried changing the `Provisioning Profile(Deprecated)` Value to `Automatic`.

[image]

This worked for me and I hope it would be helpful
 for someone.

Answer (score 1):

`Project Target -> Build Settings -> Code Signing Identity ->` Change the `Debug` and `Release` to `iOS Developer` and `iOS Distribution`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have error message like this:
[target name] is automatically signed, but provisioning profile xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx has been manually specified. Set the provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the build settings editor, or switch to manual signing in the project editor.

You can fix like this:
1. Check Automatically code sign in
2. Uncheck Automatically code sign in, then check it again and reselect the Team. Xcode then fixed whatever was causing the issue on its own
3. If still not work, find project.pbxproj, search the profile, and just delete that line, then save it.

This work for me!

Answer (score 0):

Close Xcode project.

Using finder go to project folder.

Right click on .xcodeproj and choose "Show Package Contents"

Right click on project.pbxproj go on "Open With" and choose TextEdit

Now search for your Provision Profile instanceId specified in the error message.

Delete all found texts and let Provisioning Profiles clean.
Save & Close.

Open Xcode
Enable automatically manage signing

Source: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/has+conflicting+provisioning+settings+xcode

I tried multiple things mentioned in stack but nothing worked except above solution.

Answer (score -1):

**HERE IS THE FIX**

**FOLLOW THESE STEPS:**
open your project in xcode, in my case I used xcode 9.

**INSIDE THE GENERAL TAB DO THE FOLLOWING**

**UNCHECK THE FOLLOWING OPTION:**
     Automatically manage signing

**THEN SIGN YOUR DEBUG PROFILE**
     provisioning profile should be your development profile from the dropdown
     Team : will be populated because of the above provisioning profile
     Sigining Certificate: will be populated.

**THEN SIGN YOUR RELEASE PROFILE**
     provisioning profile should be your release profile from the dropdown
     Team : will be populated because of the above provisioning profile
     Sigining Certificate: will be populated.

That is all, clean and archive your project.

Comment: You got downvotes only for this, but I tried it anyway and it worked for me. Perhaps because you and I are using xcode 9, and the question here is about xcode 8.