# App has conflicting provisioning settings in Build Settings

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-provisioning

I have generated a certificate and created a provisioning profile for my project so that I could make push notification in it, but when in `Build Setting -> CodeSigning` I write the name of provisioning profile and give my team name in General an error appears that AppName has conflicting provisioning settings.

How can I correct this?

The error looks like this

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47277940/distribution-profile-requesting-a-developer-certificate

Comment: Uncheck "Automatically manage signing", then check it again and reselect the Team. Xcode then fixed whatever was causing the issue on its own.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Distribution Profile requesting a Developer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47277940/distribution-profile-requesting-a-developer-certificate)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just uncheck `Automatically manage signing` and check it again and select appropriate team.

Xcode will automatically fix the causing issue on its own.

Comment: @siddle set as automatic

Comment: Great job @siddle

Comment: Bro the error is resolved but when i On the push notifcation from capabilites it shows an error that Add push notification in your Apple ID. @Himanth

Comment: @siddle go to developer member centre -> certificates and identifiers -> App ids -> find your app bundle id -> edit -> and then you can enable push notifications from there

Answer (score 3):

In XCODE 10.X Provisioning profile has garbage values in Provisioning Profile while running for the first time.

Go to:

> Project Target-- > Build Settings -> Double click on Provisioning Profile.

You will see `e4abcdbdbacbcd-eercdcsdcvdede-xxxxxxxxxxxx` like this, so you should delete that.

Uncheck "Automatically manage signing", then check it again and reselect the Team. Xcode then fix whatever was causing the issue on its own.

Please refer to this - it worked for me.

[Provisioning profile Conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42885122/xcode-has-conflicting-provisioning-settings/53957176#53957176)

[ios](/questions/tagged/ios)

Answer (score 2):

Goto `Build Settings -> Signing`

Set

1. Code Signing Identity to *IOS Developer* (Automatic)
2. Provisioning Profile to *Automatic*
3. Provisioning Profile(Deprecated) to *Automatic*

Uncheck "Automatically manage signing", then check it again and reselect the Team.

Comment: Bro i have done it as u have explain above but  still error not going. @Lal Krishna

Comment: Thanks i got it. @Lal Krishna

Comment: Okey. If its works for you, please accept the answer. So it may help someone in future

Comment: Bro the error is resolved but when i On the push notifcation from capabilites it shows an error that Add push notification  in your Apple ID. @Lal Krishna

Comment: Does your app have `Apple Push Services` certificate on https://developer.apple.com/ ?

Comment: yes there is appearing two color circle one with green color and second with yellow. @Lal Krishna

Answer (score 1):

Deselect automatically manage signing and select your provisioning profile in the respective field.

Comment: I have selected my provisioning profile but yet it is not removing. @Francesco Deliro