# Can't create IPA file xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipa

Right now I'm trying for days to make an iOS app, and put it on my ipad.
I can not get it because I cant find a way to generate an IPA file.
I have windows 7, and a virtual mac OS computer, which has Xcode on it, and Xamarin studio on it. In my mac, I opened a project and wrote some code to it, and then built the project, and ran it on simulator iphone.
 It did work !
Now, my next step is to generate IPA file, but I couldn't find where does the IPA file is generated after I build it on my mac. 
Can someone give me some help ?
I have been through every IPA tutorial I have found, and in Apple site.

[Trying to create provisional profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRHlk.png)

Comment: You need to go to Xcode -> Product -> Archive. Once it is completed, it will open a window where it will show the ipa file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970741/how-to-create-ipa-in-xcode-6

Comment: I'm not using Xcode. I'm using xamarin. So what should I do now ? And thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate IPA files in xamarin studio when you build, you need to go to iOS project options->iOS IPA Options. Then check the "Build iTunes Package Archive (IPA)"

[image]

Comment: And then where can I find the IPA file ?

Comment: I can only find .exe file, with the name of my app. Why is there .exe file instead of .IPA file ?

Comment: You will be able to find your IPA file in bin folder. Make sure you selected the build config is under iPhone platform. Also, make sure you have configure with correct provisioning profiles. You can check whether you configure it or not in Project Options->iOS Bundle Signing. If yes, you will be able to see the provisioning profiles selected in there.

Comment: I understand. I got stuck with this provisioning profile thing, because I can't understand something.
If I want to just generate IPA file, without upload it to the app store, I still have to pay 99$ ? If not, then how can I create a provisioning profile ?
And in addition, Im now trying to do it in the xCode as well as the xamarin, I dont care which one , I just want to be able to create IPA file.
So, another question : Are they both free ? And can you please explain me one of the ways ? I realy got stuck in this. Thx.

Comment: I edited my question. See the link . There I'm trying to create provisional profile for free in xCode in my mac, and the iOS Development "Create" Button, is disabled, I cant even see him. What should I do ?

Comment: You can check out Free Provisioning: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/free-provisioning/

Comment: I checked it. I did it, but then I got two errors :
1. Team requires a provisioning profile . Select a provisioning profile for the "Release" build ...
2. Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.1'