# Xcode 6.2 - unable to archive a build

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, xcode6, itunes

I recently updated to OSx 10.10.2 and Xcode 6.2.

I have a Unity project I'm working on that I've made for iOS and released through iTunes connect dozens of times. Now, on Xcode 6.2, once I get my project into Xcode, I can't get past the first step.

Namely, Project->Archive. I need to archive my build to get it up to iTunes Connect. However, the "Archive" option is disabled, greyed out.

How do I archive my build?
Is there a new workflow for getting things to iTunes Connect?

Thank you!

Answer (score 55):

Maybe its not the case, by check out if you have selected other destination instead iOS device. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18791703/1243134) answer.

Comment: Looks like I needed to select "iOS device" instead of "iPhone whatever." Thank you!

Comment: OMG.. so much time wasted. THANK YOU

Comment: I believe this is now "Generic iOS Device" (Xcode 8.1)

Answer (score 8):

If Archive is grayed out, it's because you have a simulator selected and did not select "Generic iOS Device". "your device" (could be your iPhone) also would work. I am Using Xcode 8 Swift 3.0.
[image]