# How to export app with Xcode 7?

Tags: xcode7

I got problem with **exporting app** in **Xcode 7**.
I tried things with older version but **they weren't work**.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812650/how-do-you-export-your-finished-application-from-xcode

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps to export your app for testing:

1. Register all test devices.
2. Archive your app.
3. Export the archive using either an ad hoc provisioning profile or team provisioning profile to code sign your app.
4. Install the app on test devices.
5. Solicit crash reports from testers

please have a look here
https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH8-SW1